# When should I use firebase's realtime database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, architecture

I want to make use of Firebase's services such as authentication and the real-time database. It makes integrating with the front-end clients very easy. However, I am struggling with the database portion. I still want a relational database, so I can more easily interact with my other data, so I thought of Rails and Postgres for this. I know Rails has ActionCable, but I want to utilize more of the services in firebase. I wanted to have my frontend clients talk to my Rails app and then have the Rails save to Postgres then transforming the data in a suitable NoSQL format for Firebase's DB. Is this a proper way of using Firebase? How else can I utilize Firebase's real-time DB without making it the source of truth?

Comment: I definitely know of some large-scale projects that use the Firebase Realtime Database as a proxy between their (legacy enterprise) infrastructure and their mobile apps. But whether that is the right approach for you, only you can tell.

Comment: My question is being marked for "too broad", is there another website that allows me to have architecture discussions with people? Stackoverflow format is too constricting and doesn't allow fruitful discussion.

Comment: This question is legit.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do it. I usually do things like that using an event source architecture.
Let's say I have a class called `User` and I want to keep them in sync with a `user` collection on firebase. For that purpose, I would put a listener on `User`:

**models/user_observer.rb**

```
class UserObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  include Wisper::Publisher

  def initialize
    subscribe(FirebaseUserPublisher, async: true)
    super
  end

  def after_save(user)
    publish_changes_to_firebase(user)
  end
end
```

so that, every time a user is changed/created, the changes will be **async** reflected on your firebase and the `FirebaseUserPublisher` class will take care of it.

Remember that this means *eventual consistency*: if the `FirebaseUserPublisher` fails, your data is out of sync

Answer (score 2):

This is basically what we are doing in a large collaborative web-application. We have a Java-based backend which watches specific keys in our Firebase RTDB for changes/additions/deletions, and responds accordingly. It uses the data from Firebase and then fires up a new Apache Mesos executor for each workspace that is currently active in our web-application (Has "presence"), with each instance having its own PostgreSQL database that the executor uses. This database is populated using data scattered around our RTDB.

When we want to have the backend perform a long-running calculation or task for the client, we write some data to a specific location ("dbRequests") outlining the task we want and some user-defined parameters. The backend executor reads the request and then goes off and spawns a worker service to execute the task for us. Once that is done, it writes new data as a child to the original request which the client picks-up and displays to the user (Or, in the case of reports, opens a new tab with the rendered charts using the calculated data). Generally, it works well for our use-case: many connected users working in a digital workspace with live updates for each connected client.

The biggest problem we've faced using this model is running data migration scripts, and managing all of the data we have in the RTDB. To be expected I suppose, since it's essentially a giant JSON-structure ;).